# Define a resource under another package (except the main package)

Tags: java, android, package, android-resources

I have a Gradle Android project (in Android Studio) that includes two packages (**both in `app` module**). You know then there are two sets of folders under `src/main/java` directory:

```
src/main/java/the/first/pkg/...{The Files Under First Package}...
src/main/java/the/second/pkg/...{The Files Under Second Package}...
```

---

<sub>Note: Both first and second packages are in a folder that named `main`. But I mean, from the ***main package***, my ***first package***. In other words you can see this in `main/AndroidManifest.xml` file:</sub>

<sup>`<manifest ... package="the.first.pkg">`</sup>

---

But what about `src/main/res` directory?! ***All resources have been located in the root of this path (not categorized by package name)!***

Now how can I define a `resource` (like a `layout`) *NOT under the first package*, but **under the second package**? (So I would be able to access it in my `java` code through **`the.second.pkg.R.layout.resource_name`**.)

Answer (score 1):

You should change your scheme a little bit. By default, `Android Studio` creates `main` package and put all your sources in it, like this:

[image]

If you want to get different res folders, for different packages you should define another package inside `src` package:

[image]

Also, `Android Studio` can generate it for you:

> 1. Open the Project pane and select the Project view from the drop-down menu at the top of the pane.
> 2. Navigate to MyProject/app/src/.
> 3. Right-click the src directory and select New > Folder > Java Folder.
> 4. From the drop-down menu next to Target Source Set, select debug.
> 5. Click Finish.

It's called `source sets` more detail you can get from this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. "By default, `Android Studio` creates `main` package and ...". Does `main` back to "main package"? But `main` folder includes both of my packages!! 
Another point: `debug` is the name of a `BuildType`, not a `package` name! 
Another point: Why `Java Folder`? Why not `Res Folder`? 
Anyway thank for your information and also the helpful link. I didn't know about them before.